# Change the arrow background and position in flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

i have this vertical slider using flex and here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smt93yzw/) of it.

I tried to look online for changing the position of the `prev` and `next` but i could not do it and also wanted to use the arrow on top and bottom side of the image but could not find the appropriate css for that.

If the arrow doesnt work and someone tells me how to style the dots below the slider for navigation than it will be enough as well.

Please guide me in right direction for that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser's web inspector to view the HTML markup that the Flexslider plugin generates. There are plenty of classes that you can target via CSS to style the previous and next links, namely `flex-nav-prev`, `flex-prev`, `flex-nav-next` and `flex-next`:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <div class="flex-viewport">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="well clone"></li>
      <li class="well"></li>
      <li class="well"></li>
      <li class="well flex-active-slide"></li>
      <li class="well clone"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
    <li>
      <a class="">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="flex-active">3</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li class="flex-nav-prev">
      <a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-nav-next">
      <a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```